# ERROR in [at-loader] cannot find module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I'm not the best with JS and the whole ecosystem so please bear with me if I miss speak. I'll do my best to describe the issue.

I'm using TypeScript and ReactJS. From my limited knowledge, it seems that the TypeScript definitions aren't applying on build. I don't understand why.

My stack is babel, gulp, webpack, TypeScript, React.

**errors:**

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/scripts/chromereload.ts:22:7 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'chrome'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/scripts/chromereload.ts:22:67 
    TS7006: Parameter 'tabs' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/scripts/chromereload.ts:25:11 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'chrome'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/scripts/chromereload.ts:27:9 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'chrome'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/scripts/contentscript.tsx:18:12 
    TS2345: Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any>'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | ComponentClass<any> | StatelessComponent<any>' is not assignable to type 'string | StatelessComponent<any> | ComponentClass<any>'.
      Type 'ComponentClass<any>' is not assignable to type 'string | StatelessComponent<any> | ComponentClass<any>'.
        Type 'React.ComponentClass<any>' is not assignable to type 'React.ComponentClass<any>'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
          Type 'React.Component<any, React.ComponentState>' is not assignable to type 'React.Component<any, React.ComponentState>'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
            Types of property 'render' are incompatible.
              Type '() => string | number | false | Element | Element[] | ReactPortal' is not assignable to type '() => false | Element'.
                Type 'string | number | false | Element | Element[] | ReactPortal' is not assignable to type 'false | Element'.
                  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'false | Element'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/scripts/contentscript.tsx:18:12 
    TS2605: JSX element type 'App' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Property 'setState' is missing in type 'App'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/scripts/lib/utils.ts:49:5 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'chrome'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/scripts/lib/utils.ts:49:63 
    TS7006: Parameter 'tabs' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/scripts/react/app.tsx:26:19 
    TS2552: Cannot find name 'ReactElement'. Did you mean 'SVGRectElement'?

ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/scripts/react/app.tsx:36:10 
    TS2339: Property 'state' does not exist on type 'App'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/scripts/react/app.tsx:39:15 
    TS2339: Property 'state' does not exist on type 'App'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/scripts/react/app.tsx:43:31 
    TS2339: Property 'state' does not exist on type 'App'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/scripts/react/app.tsx:48:44 
    TS2339: Property 'state' does not exist on type 'App'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3420:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'a' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3421:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'abbr' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3422:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'address' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3423:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'area' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AreaHTMLAttributes<HTMLAreaElement>, HTMLAreaElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AreaHTMLAttributes<HTMLAreaElement>, HTMLAreaElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3424:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'article' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3425:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'aside' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3426:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'audio' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AudioHTMLAttributes<HTMLAudioElement>, HTMLAudioElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AudioHTMLAttributes<HTMLAudioElement>, HTMLAudioElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3427:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'b' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3428:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'base' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<BaseHTMLAttributes<HTMLBaseElement>, HTMLBaseElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<BaseHTMLAttributes<HTMLBaseElement>, HTMLBaseElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3429:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'bdi' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3430:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'bdo' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3431:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'big' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3432:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'blockquote' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<BlockquoteHTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<BlockquoteHTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3433:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'body' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLBodyElement>, HTMLBodyElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLBodyElement>, HTMLBodyElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3434:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'br' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLBRElement>, HTMLBRElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLBRElement>, HTMLBRElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3435:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'button' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3436:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'canvas' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<CanvasHTMLAttributes<HTMLCanvasElement>, HTMLCanvasElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<CanvasHTMLAttributes<HTMLCanvasElement>, HTMLCanvasElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3437:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'caption' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3438:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'cite' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3439:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'code' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3440:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'col' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ColHTMLAttributes<HTMLTableColElement>, HTMLTableColElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ColHTMLAttributes<HTMLTableColElement>, HTMLTableColElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3441:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'colgroup' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ColgroupHTMLAttributes<HTMLTableColElement>, HTMLTableColElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ColgroupHTMLAttributes<HTMLTableColElement>, HTMLTableColElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3442:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'data' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3443:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'datalist' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDataListElement>, HTMLDataListElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDataListElement>, HTMLDataListElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3444:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'dd' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3445:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'del' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<DelHTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<DelHTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3446:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'details' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<DetailsHTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<DetailsHTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3447:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'dfn' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3448:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'dialog' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3449:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'div' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3450:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'dl' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDListElement>, HTMLDListElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDListElement>, HTMLDListElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3451:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'dt' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3452:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'em' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3453:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'embed' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<EmbedHTMLAttributes<HTMLEmbedElement>, HTMLEmbedElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<EmbedHTMLAttributes<HTMLEmbedElement>, HTMLEmbedElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3454:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'fieldset' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<FieldsetHTMLAttributes<HTMLFieldSetElement>, HTMLFieldSetElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<FieldsetHTMLAttributes<HTMLFieldSetElement>, HTMLFieldSetElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3455:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'figcaption' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3456:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'figure' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3457:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'footer' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3458:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'form' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<FormHTMLAttributes<HTMLFormElement>, HTMLFormElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<FormHTMLAttributes<HTMLFormElement>, HTMLFormElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3459:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'h1' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>, HTMLHeadingElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>, HTMLHeadingElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3460:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'h2' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>, HTMLHeadingElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>, HTMLHeadingElement>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3461:13 
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'h3' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>, HTMLHeadingElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>, HTMLHeadingElement>'.
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "precommit-msg": "echo 'Pre-commit checks...' && exit 0",
    "lint": "node node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js app/scripts.babel/**/*.js"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "precommit-msg",
    "lint"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^14.4.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint": "^4.4.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^11.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.4.3",
    "gulp-chrome-manifest": "0.0.13",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-size": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "^8.1.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "gulp-useref": "^3.0.8",
    "gulp-zip": "^3.2.0",
    "main-bower-files": "^2.11.1",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.5",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "wiredep": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "env": {
      "node": true,
      "browser": true
    },
    "globals": {
      "chrome": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "eol-last": 0,
      "quotes": [
        2,
        "single"
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/chrome": "0.0.48",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "@types/react": "^16.0.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "github:webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#v1.0.1",
    "babel-es6-polyfill": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "ejsx": "^1.0.0-b2",
    "gulp-javascript-obfuscator": "^1.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-shadow": "^2.0.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "ts-deferred": "^1.0.4",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5"
  }
}
```

***tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/scripts/",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es6",
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "types": []        
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "./app/scripts/**/*.{ts,tsx}"
    ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import UglifyJsPlugin from 'uglifyjs-webpack-plugin';

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/scripts');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/scripts');

var config = {
  entry: {
    'contentscript': APP_DIR + '/contentscript.tsx',
    'background': APP_DIR + '/background.ts',
    'chromereload': APP_DIR + '/chromereload.ts'
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  //devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
        '.js',
        '.ts',
        '.tsx'
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new UglifyJsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
        // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
    ]
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```